# How to save an environment, all its objects and child environments into a single file, in R

Tags: r, save, load, parent-child, environment

I could not find a way to save an environment in R that includes all its child environments and objects.

```
e <- new.env(parent=emptyenv())
e$foo <- 3
ee <- new.env(parent=e)
ee$bar <- 13
save(e, file="temp.RData")
#####
remove(e, ee)
load("temp.RData) ### Does not load e and ee
```

I appreciate your answer the proper way to do it. 
And similar question: how can I remove an environment including all its child environments? 
If this is not the proper way to get the job done (having layers of environments and saving all together through the parent environment), what is the proper way to do so in R?

Comment: "Proper way" is subjective and heavily dependent on your use-case. If you provide context to how you want to use it, then perhaps we can opine. Since SO is about programming issues, it would likely be best to clearly state an example use-case to go along with your proposed (not-working) code above. BTW: one method would be to include the child environment as a variable in the parent; that is, `e$ee <- new.env(parent=emptyenv())`, so `save(e, file="...")` and `load("...")` works as expected.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It will solve the problem anyways.

Comment: About the use-case: There are clients, each might have several members, and each client has some portfolios available to members, each members might have several portfolios available to herself only. Each portfolio is a list with elements and properties.
Each member can access to her portfolio elements and all its parent client, not others.
In my mind, it is a hierarchy of folders (or buckets) that contains so many files (or objects) and sub-folders.
I thought using environments are the best way to model such structure.
Appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: Though there are some advantages (well, certainly *differences*, some performance-related) between using environments and lists, I don't see why a `list` couldn't satisfy your needs here as well. Just a thought, like I said it's subjective.

Comment: Yes, it seems environment adds no better functionality that lists.

Comment: Although I wish environments were closer to the bucket concept that has children (other environment) and elements (lists/dataframes). The current structure of environment makes it very identical to lists. :)